# DAPR and Zipkin missing spanid

Tags: trace, zipkin, dapr

I'm getting the following error viewing my traces in Zipkin

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spanId')
at ao (Timeline.tsx:88:50)
at Xo (react-dom.production.min.js:153:146)
at ms (react-dom.production.min.js:261:496)
at cl (react-dom.production.min.js:246:265)
at sl (react-dom.production.min.js:246:194)
at $s (react-dom.production.min.js:239:172)
at react-dom.production.min.js:123:115
at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19:467)
at Gi (react-dom.production.min.js:122:325)
at Yi (react-dom.production.min.js:123:61)
```

When I look at the data that is retrieved from the zipkin service I can indeed see that the trace has no spanId

```
[
  {
    "traceId": "8820012910cdb32bb41316551a150715",
    "parentId": "42836ff2aac7d271",
    "id": "498a8343e43beb74",
    "kind": "SERVER",
    "name": "calllocal/liftservice/lift",
    "timestamp": 1678755356047932,
    "duration": 198974,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "liftservice"
    },
    "tags": {
      "dapr.api": "/dapr.proto.internals.v1.ServiceInvocation/CallLocal",
      "dapr.invoke_method": "Lift",
      "dapr.protocol": "grpc",
      "otel.library.name": "dapr-diagnostics",
      "rpc.service": "ServiceInvocation",
      "service.name": "liftservice"
    }
...
  }
```

I'm assuming I've misconfigured something but I can't find anything in Google or the Dapr docs to tell me what I've got wrong here

My dapr config currently looks like this

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: daprsystem
spec:
  mtls:
    enabled: true
  tracing:
    samplingRate: "1"
    zipkin:
      endpointAddress: "http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans"
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Also hitting the same problem, but can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: Not yet, I've switched over to using the Azure Monitor exporter which was my end goal. This seems to work ok in initial tests